# Print numpy array without brackets

Tags: python, numpy

I am in the process of trying to teach myself python so I am very new to this. My code is pretty simple. 
I just have a numpy array that I have randomly generated with integers. My code looks like this

```
arr = np.random.randint(100, size=(5,5))

print(arr)
```

When it prints it prints with brackets around it like this

```
[[98 87 45  5 67]
 [33 39  1 40 96]
 [97 55 85  2 65]
 [18 28 32 55 21]
 [96 46 14 87 28]]
```

How do I remove all of the brackets so it is only the numbers with the spaces between?

Comment: you can use `re.sub` to replace the brackets after converting the bumpy array to a string  `import re` `print(re.sub('[\[\]]', '', np.array_str(arr)))`

Comment: I think you should learn to love those brackets :)   They provide useful visual information.  But as a programming learning task,  it's mostly Python string handling.   It's not much of a `numpy` task.  Still it might be useful to look at the code for `np.savetxt`, and try to imitate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
for el in arr:
     print(' '.join(el.astype(str)))
```

Comment: It returns an error 

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.int32 found

Comment: No worries, please consider upvoting, and mark this post as an answer to close it off

Answer (score 3):

What about using Pandas?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.random.randint(100, size=(5,5))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)


print(df.to_string(header=False, index=False))

 45  40  99   8  20
 29  18  54  52  51
 94  52  84  61  17
 44  54  38  48  62
  4  76  95  73  46
```

Answer (score 2):

for example

```
import numpy as np
import re
arr = np.random.randint(100, size=(5,5))
print(arr)
print(re.sub('[\[\]]', '', np.array_str(arr)))
```

output:

```
[[71 35 79 89 85]
 [36 77 25 80 53] 
 [26 56  6 49 82]
 [27 84 18 86 62]
 [32 39 83 78 14]]

71 35 79 89 85
 36 77 25 80 53
 26 56  6 49 82
 27 84 18 86 62
 32 39 83 78 14
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in arr:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=' ')
```